# Does std::atomic::operator++ really return by value?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, atomic, std

According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith) prefix `std::atomic<T>::operator++` returns a `T`, so this code only increments `v` once:

```
template<class T> void addTwo(std::atomic<T>& v) {
  ++(++v);
}
```

Also, `std::atomic<T>::operator=` [apparently](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator%3D) returns a `T`, so this code dereferences an invalid pointer that used to point to a temporary `T`:

```
template<class T>
void setOneThenTwo(std::atomic<T>& v) {
  auto ptr = &(v = 1);
  *ptr = 2;
}
```

I am most certainly not suggesting that these code patterns are good practice, however it is highly surprising to me that `std::atomic` breaks them. I always expect `operator=` and prefix `operator++` to return a reference to `*this`.

**Question:** Is cppreference right about the return types here, and if so, is there a good reason for having `std::atomic` behave differently than built-in types in this regard?

Comment: If `operator=` returns a `T`, then `&(v = 1)` should not even compile, right?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Because it's an rvalue temporary?

Comment: Does it return an lvalue? If not then the second ++ won't compile so at least you'll be saved from buggy behaviour if you did expect that to wrok.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit because it's a prvalue. So, yes, some atomic operations may return by value contrary to common usage, but only bad compilers will allow either of these examples to compile.

Comment: Bad compilers, or (unlikely) bad types `T` that specialize `std::atomic` and for which prefix `operator++` is a member function that can bind to an rvalue. But if you're specializing `std::atomic` for your user-defined type, you really should know `std::atomic` well enough to know not to do that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

if `operator++` returned a reference, it would have been a reference to `std::atomic<T>` not to `T` in which case you would need to do an additional `load` to get the current value.

Imagine you've got a DBMS and you need to maintain an 'autoincrement' field

With  `operator++` retuning `T` you can do this

```
class AutoIncrement
{
public:
   AutoIncrement() : current (0) {}

   unsigned int next()
   {
      return ++current;
   }

private:
   std::atomic<unsigned int> current;
};
```

Now imagine `operator++` returns `std::atomic<T>&`
In that case when you do `return ++current` it will do two things

1. Atomic read-modify-write
2. Atomic load

They are two totally independent operations. If other thread calls `next` in between you will get wrong value for your autoincrement field!

Comment: +1. In short it's because atomic (increment and return the new value) is so much more useful than (atomic increment) and (return a reference to the atomic object), that the designers feel it justifies the slightly surprising return type.

Comment: Please don't deface your answers with an edit. This has been rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

According to `[C++11: 29.6.5/32]` and `[C++11: 29.6.5/10]`, yes, [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator%3D) is correct in this regard.

I'm not qualified to tell you why.