# std::atomic is thread safe in two sequence points in a line?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, stdatomic

```
std::atomic<int> atomic_number = 0
std::thread t;

while (1) {
    t = std::thread(f);
    t.detach();
}
```

```
void f() {
    if ((++atomic_number) < 5) { // the total operation line
    }
}
```

In this code, maybe, `++atomic_number` operation runs, and the `atomic_number < 5` operation runs. That is, there are the two sequence points in the line. So, can I say that the total operation line is thread safe?

Or, the other atomic_number operation of other thread can barge between the operations?

Comment: @NathanOliver There's only one atomic operation, `fetch_add` called by `operator++`. It returns a new value after the increment, which is then compared to 5. No additional loads are performed.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oops.  Missed that it returned by value so only the ++ operation is atomic.

Comment: *"and the `atomic_number < 5` operation runs"* -- where does this occur in your code? I see only the result of `++atomic_number` being compared to `5`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith - note the return value is plain `int`, not a reference.  There's only one atomic access to the variable.  You're right that `++num` and then a separate read of `num` would be a problem, that's why that isn't what this means.  [Does std::atomic::operator++ really return by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13231048) explains that this is why `std::atomic` isn't designed that way.